# Symfony - Get Object from a custom query

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

I try to get an array of my object named "Entreprise".

Here my custom query (in EntrepriseRepository.php) :

```
    $qb = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p.nom,p.adresse,p.ville,p.latitude,p.longitude,p.photo')
    ->addSelect('(6371 * acos(cos(radians(:lat)) * cos(radians(p.latitude)) * cos(radians(p.longitude) - radians(:lng)) + sin(radians(:lat)) * sin(radians(p.latitude)))) AS distance')
    ->having('distance <= 50')
    ->setParameter('lat', $lat) 
    ->setParameter('lng', $lng) ;

   // return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT);
```

I have a relation between my Entity "Disponibilite" and "Entreprise":

Disponibilite.orm.yml :

```
manyToOne:
    est_propose_par:
        targetEntity: Entreprise 
        inversedBy: propose
```

Entreprise.orm.yml :

```
oneToMany:
    propose:
        targetEntity: Disponibilite 
        mappedBy: est_propose_par
```

I want to get any "Disponibilite" of my "Entreprise" :

```
{% for entreprise in entreprises %}
 {% for disponibilite in entreprise.propose %}
  <td>{{ disponibilite.dateDispo|date('H:i') }}</td>
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here the error :

```
Key "propose" for array with keys "nom, adresse, ville, latitude, longitude, photo, distance" does not exist.
```

I think it's because I don't return the whole object "Entreprise" but I don't know how I have to modify my custom request. Thank you for any help

EDIT :

With this update :

```
->select ('p');
```

My Controller :

```
 $entreprises = $repositoryEntreprise->selectEntreprises($latitude,$longitude);
      return $this->render('CalandmeBundle:Default:recherche.html.twig',array('adresse' => $adresse,'latitude'=>$latitude,
      'longitude'=>$longitude,'entreprises'=>$entreprises));
```

I get this :

```
'entreprises' => array(array(object(Entreprise), 'distance' => '0.6023921078894118')
```

But I can't use the object 'Entreprise':

```
Key "photo" for array with keys "0, distance" does not exist.
```

Here my result when I write in Twig `{{ dump (entreprises[3][0] ) }}` :

```
Entreprise {#364 ▼
  -id: 12
  -nom: "Ainsi Soit Tif"
  -adresse: "47 Mail Albert 1er"
  -ville: "Amiens"
  -codePostal: 80000
  -description: "..."
  -est_possede_par: Professionnel {#369 ▶}
  -rendez_vous: PersistentCollection {#365 ▶}
  -pratique: PersistentCollection {#371 ▶}
  -est_pratique_par: null
  -latitude: 49.888718
  -longitude: 2.29876
  -photo: "img/coiffeur4.jpg"
  +propose: PersistentCollection {#367 ▶}
}
```

So I try to get all informations of the first "Entreprise" :

```
{% for entreprise in entreprises[0][0] %}
```

But It doesn't works..

If I write in Twig :

```
{{ entreprises[0][0].nom }}
```

It works

If I write in Twig :

```
   {% for disponibilite in entreprises[0][0].propose %}
<td> {{ disponibilite.dateDispo|date('Y-m-d')}} </td>
   {% endfor %}
```

It works too.

But just for the first one 'Entreprise', Why I can't use ??:

```
{% for entreprise in entreprises[0][0] %}
```

Here the result with `dump(entreprises):`

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:8 [▼
    0 => Entreprise {#289 ▶}
    "distance" => "0.6023921078894118"
    "photo" => "img/coiffeur.jpg"
    "nom" => "Chambre Air"
    "adresse" => "33 Rue St Leu"
    "ville" => "Amiens"
    "latitude" => 49.8985177
    "longitude" => 2.3005478
  ]
  1 => array:8 [▼
    0 => Entreprise {#335 ▶}
    "distance" => "0.49092062431986955"
    "photo" => "img/coiffeur2.jpg"
    "nom" => "Atmosp Hair"
    "adresse" => "25 Rue Vanmarcke"
    "ville" => "Amiens"
    "latitude" => 49.896528
    "longitude" => 2.301443
  ]
  2 => array:8 [▼
    0 => Entreprise {#356 ▶}
    "distance" => "0.18742302911019457"
    "photo" => "img/coiffeur3.jpg"
    "nom" => "Sam la Coup"
    "adresse" => "8 Rue du Général Leclerc"
    "ville" => "Amiens"
    "latitude" => 49.894634
    "longitude" => 2.293289
  ]
  3 => array:8 [▼
    0 => Entreprise {#364 ▶}
    "distance" => "0.6325871662424426"
    "photo" => "img/coiffeur4.jpg"
    "nom" => "Ainsi Soit Tif"
    "adresse" => "47 Mail Albert 1er"
    "ville" => "Amiens"
    "latitude" => 49.888718
    "longitude" => 2.29876
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

update your select statement.

```
->select('p')
```

in twig try to access with in 1D loop

```
{% for disponibilite in entreprise.propose %}
    <td>{{ disponibilite.dateDispo|date('H:i') }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

if it is not working then

```
{% for disponibilite in entreprise[0].propose %}
    <td>{{ disponibilite.dateDispo|date('H:i') }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

or return your result like

```
$result =  $qb->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT);

return $result[0];
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for help. If I try this, I get this error : 'Key "photo" for array with keys "0, distance" does not exist.'
In Twig I call all this informations : "p.nom,p.adresse,p.ville,p.latitude,p.longitude,p.photo"

Comment: try this {% for disponibilite in entreprise[0].propose %}

Comment: I had this idea but it's a little bit strange, I update the post for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood, you want all `Disponibilite` of an `Enterprise`. If so, then why don't you use a join inside your custom query? Like:

```
//EntrepriseRepository.php
$qb = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->leftJoin('p.propose', 'd')
    ->select('p.nom,p.adresse,p.ville,p.latitude,p.longitude,p.photo, d.id //ADD OTHER FIELDS HERE TO BE SELECTED FROM Disponibilite ENTITY')
    ->addSelect('(6371 * acos(cos(radians(:lat)) * cos(radians(p.latitude)) * cos(radians(p.longitude) - radians(:lng)) + sin(radians(:lat)) * sin(radians(p.latitude)))) AS distance')
    ->having('distance <= 50')
    ->setParameter('lat', $lat) 
    ->setParameter('lng', $lng)
;

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(); //I THINK THAT IF YOU USE JUST ->getResult() IT WILL RETURN AN ARRAY OF OBJECTS BY DEFAULT. AND ONLY IF YOU WANT TO RETURN AN ARRAY OF ARRAYS THEN USE ->getArrayResult()
```

Then you can use `{{ dump(entreprises) }}` to see what's inside that array, and then see how you need to create the iterations to display `Disponibilite`.

And btw, that `entreprise[0]` is looking ugly.

Comment: Hi,
I updated my post. If I use the dump on 'entreprises', I see in my array : an other array of my Objects 'Entreprise' and the value of distance.

Comment: @devicz You need to select your fields from the `Disponibilite` entity in the custom query as I've wrote you in the comment there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just had to use this :

```
 {% for entreprise in entreprises %}
```

And call for any parameters :

```
 {{ entreprises[0].nom }}
```

And :

```
{% for disponibilite in entreprise[0].propose %}
<td> {{ disponibilite.dateDispo|date('HH:mm') }} </td>
{% endfor %}
```